# How to restrict the privilege of kubectl command

Tags: kubernetes

I would like to grant one user only the "get" privilege of "kubectl" command. I suppose it should be done with RBAC, anyone can advise it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `allow-get.yaml` file with the next content and change `my-user` by your user, and run `kubectl apply -f allow-get.yaml`

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: allow-get
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - "*"
  verbs:
  - get
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: allow-get-bind
subjects:
  - kind: User
    name: my-user
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: allow-get
```